# Question about center of dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I need suggestions for this exercise.

Let $D_{2n}$ stand for the dihedral group of $2n$ elements.

1. Show that if $n$ is odd and $\forall b \in D_{2n} (ab = ba)$, then $a = e$.
2. Show that if $n$ is even, then there is $a\in D_{2n}$ such that $\forall b \in D_{2n} (ab = ba)$ and $a \neq e$.

My ideas: The elements in $G$ can separated into two disjoint sets: $Q=\{a\in G : a^2\neq e\}$ and $G\setminus Q$. If $a\in Q$, then $a\neq a^{-1}$ and this implies that $a$ is not of order 2.

Also, any suggestions of introductory books on abstract algebra are welcome.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you're asking. Your English needs some work. What's more is that your title should be more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks, you are any suggerent?, Because english is not my first language, and this exercise i have only in spanish language.

Comment: Well, for a start, it's "suggestions", not "suggerent".

Comment: The book *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra"* by Gallian is a great resource with plenty of exercises, half of which with solutions.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1469131/104041).

Comment: [This duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/78447/104041) might be better.